# Why doesn't the redirect_url parm work on my Vimeo ajax POST?

Tags: javascript, ajax, upload, vimeo-api

I am experiencing a problem using the Vimeo upload API to upload a video to Vimeo from our webpage, even though I have the proper "Accept" header set to version 3.4 as designated on Vimeo's API pages. Can anyone advise as to why the redirect_url parm is not working? Everything else works and the video is uploaded, but the redirect does not occur. Here is my complete page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link href="/include/jquerymmenu/jquery.mmenu.all.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos',
        upload: {
                approach: "post",
                redirect_url: 'https://www.example.com'
            },
        headers: {
             'Authorization': 'bearer ' + '<<my token here>>',
             'Content-Type': 'application/json',
             'Accept': 'application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4'
           },
        
        success: function(res){
            console.log(res);
            // Write the form to the page
            $("div#myform").html(res.upload.form);
        },
        error: function(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
</script>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myform"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you say "redirect does not occur" what exactly happens? Are you taken to another page, does the page reload, do you encounter an error message, or something else?

Comment: Once the upload completes, the user is taken to the default Vimeo "upload complete" page, which is by design according to the Vimeo docs.

Answer (score 0):

After much hair pulling I've come up with a workaround for the Vimeo POST bug that does not support the redirect_url parm (their tech support has admitted it is a current bug).

Below is the complete working php page. Unlike the vimeo samples, it is actually COMMENTED and COMPLETE!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link href="/include/jquerymmenu/jquery.mmenu.all.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="application/javascript">
//*************************************************************
// UPLOAD A VIDEO TO YOUR VIMEO ACCOUNT DIRECTLY FROM A WEB PAGE
// INCLUDING THE USE OF A REDIRECT_URL
//
// This is a hack of the Vimeo POST method of sending a video to Vimeo 
// since the Vimeo POST method has a bug which does not support the 
// redirect_url parameter.
//
// This page is completely self-contained. It makes an initial call
// to Vimeo in order to initialize the upload and displays the form
// returned from the initial call to the user, enabling them to 
// select their video and upload it. Following successful upload, 
// the user is redirected to the page they designate in sRedirectURL below
// along with any additional querystring parameters they wish to pass along
// to the target page (sAdditionalQuerystringParms).
//
//*************************************************************
// Define the redirect URL including the http or https prefix. such as https://example.com or http://example.com/folder/page.ext
var sRedirectURL = encodeURI('https://example.com');
// Define any additional querystring parameters STARTING WITH '&' (don't start with the usual '?')
// If there are no additional querystring parms, just set sAdditionalQuerystringParms = urlencode('');
// NOTE: We need to use the PHP urlencode instead of javascript encodeURI since javascript's encodeURI converts the 
// '&' to &amp; whereas the PHP urlencode converts '&' to the needed '%26'
var sAdditionalQuerystringParms = "<?php echo urlencode('&mytest=1');?>";

// Make the initial call to Vimeo which upon "success" will return a 'res' object containing the upload.form contents we need to display 
// the upload form to the user.
$.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos',
        upload: { 
            approach: "post"
           },
        headers: {
             'Authorization': 'bearer ' + '<<YOUR ACCESS TOKEN HERE>>',
             'Content-Type': 'application/json',
             'Accept': 'application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4'
           },
        
        // Initial Vimeo call successful, now display the actual upload form to the user.
        success: function(res){
            console.log(res);
            // Write the form to the page
            $("div#myform").html(res.upload.form);
            
            // search the form's action= value and replace vimeo.com%2Fupload%2Fapi with the actual sRedirectURL 
            
            // fetch the current action
            var sAction = $("div#myform > form").attr("action");
            // search and replace the current redirect_url which VIMEO sets to itself, with our own redirect url
            var sNewAction = sAction.replace('https%3A%2F%2Fvimeo.com%2Fupload%2Fapi', sRedirectURL);
            // append any additional querystring parameters we wish to send to our redirect url besides the ones sent to our 
            // redirect from vimeo
            $("div#myform > form").attr("action",sNewAction + sAdditionalQuerystringParms);
            
            // At this point, the form is being displayed on the page and it's up to the user to select their video and press SUBMIT
            // to send their video to Vimeo.
        },
        error: function(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
</script>

<title>Test Vimeo Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myform"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you very much for this workaround. Kind of suspect that this big of a bug has not been fixed after months later. I'm encountering an issue where my name field isn't saving as the video's title and I'm wondering if it's similar to this issue with the redirect_url.

Comment: This should probably be a comment on the "workaround" answer, not an answer of its own.  It doesn't provide a workaround or solution of its own, and it also poses another question

Comment: Obviously this is the case.